# Reference bold version without using font-weight: bold?

Tags: css, webfonts

I'm using webfonts on a site. For certain headings (`h1`, `h2`, etc.) I'm using bold variants (and setting `font-weight` to normal) because they look much better than using the regular variant and leaving the h-tags with the default bold weight. It's necessary to specify `font-weight: normal` because otherwise "the bold is bolded", which looks really terrible.

The problem I'm having is, how do I specify standard web fonts as fallback fonts and have the bold setting "restored"?

So for example I might do something like:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "My bold webfont";
    src: url("url/of/webfont/bold/variant");
}

h1 {
    font-family: "My bold webfont", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal; 
}
```

As long as the webfont is present we have no problem, but if the webfont fails we end up with non-bold Arial.

Is there a way to specify "Arial Bold" in the `font-family` of the `h1` (I know that doesn't work, but it's the desired goal)? Or perhaps in the `@font-face` definition I can say "this applies only to the bold version of whatever it's assigned to" – so I can omit the `font-weight: normal` from the `h1` style?

Comment: Have you tried a numeric value like `500`? Considering that your webfonts supports that size and Arial doesn't, the latter might fallback to `normal` (it's just a thought, i haven't tried it). I can't really see how this can be done with `CSS` in a *clean* way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying `font-weight: bold` in both places:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "My bold webfont";
    src: url("url/of/webfont/bold/variant");
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "My bold webfont", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://dabblet.com/gist/3504746) `p#one` shows this technique in use; if you look at it in a browser that doesn't support WOFF webfonts, you'll see the default font in bold.

Comment: I think OP wants `font-weight: normal` for web font and `bold` only when web font fails and other being used.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: That's what specifying `font-weight: bold` in the `@font-face` does - it makes the browser assume that the font is already bold.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: Take a look at the demo.

Comment: Yes! That's it. We tell @font-face "this font family definition assumes whatever style is using it will be bold, so don't go bolding it again". It is working perfectly - thank you!